# How can I get the minimum value of a column based on the another column value?(I don't think this is a duplicate, couldn't find any answer here)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have this dataframe:

```
dict = {'Group':[234, 345, 234, 456], 'Value':[5000, 2000, 1000, 3000], 'name':['abc','def','ghi','jkl']}
df = pd.Datafram(dict)

df:
   Group  Value name
0    234   5000  abc
1    345   2000  def
2    234   1000  ghi
3    456   3000  jkl
```

I want to get the minimum value from the column value depending on the group and put it in a new column next to name:

For example for the Group '234' the minimum value will be '1000' and I want the new df to look like:

```
   Group  Value  name min
0    234   5000  abc 1000
1    345   2000  def 2000
2    234   1000  ghi 1000
3    456   3000  jkl 3000
```

I tried doing the following:

```
df['min']=  df.loc[df['Group'] == df['Group'], 'Value'].min()
```

This gives me :

```
   Group  Value name   min
0    234   5000  abc  1000
1    345   2000  def  1000
2    234   1000  ghi  1000
3    456   3000  jkl  1000
```

It is not taking the group dependency. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try [groupby transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': [234, 345, 234, 456],
                   'Value': [5000, 2000, 1000, 3000],
                   'name': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']})

df['min'] = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].transform('min')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Group  Value name   min
0    234   5000  abc  1000
1    345   2000  def  2000
2    234   1000  ghi  1000
3    456   3000  jkl  3000
```